# C# Stop thread syntax execution without blocking the process

Tags: c#, multithreading, naudio

*Need to stop thread syntax execution somewhere without blocking the whole process.* ***a Noob & Odd Problem.***

**Explanation:**
There is a thread running which records a sound which has to wait somewhere until recording finishes to stop the process. The `StopIt()` is into `Recorder()` method and i need to syntax execution to be paused after `waveIn.StartRecord()` and before 
`StopIt()` until the `bool StopRecording` flips.

**The Problem:** The whole `StopIt()` takes a takes a while to do its job but i need it restart the process immediately to not lose the first bytes of the upcoming track so i needed to put the both `Recorder()` and `StopIt()` in the same thread to be able to access the data which `Recorder()` captured AND be able to run the same process in another thread to not lose any data while the first thread finishes its job.

**Attempts:**
Tried to solve the problem with many *"Wrong But It Might Work"* ways like:
`while (StopRecording) {}` but they caused many problems.

**The Code:**

```
void Recorder()
{
    waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
    waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
    waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;
    Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(ExportFolder + @"\" + titleSongName + ".mp3", waveIn.WaveFormat, BitRate);
    waveIn.StartRecording();
    //Need The Pause Here
    StopIt();
}

void StopIt()
{
    // while (StopRecording == true) { }
    waveIn.StopRecording();
    Writer.Flush();
    waveIn.Dispose();
    Writer.Dispose();
    Tagger();
}

static void waveIn_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    // signal that recording has finished
    stopRecording = true;
}

static void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    // write recorded data to MP3 writer
    if (Writer != null)
        Writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just call `StopIt()` in `waveIn_RecordingStopped`?

Comment: What do you mean with `syntax`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev waveIn_RecordingStopped rasies when StopIt() is called (to raise the waveIn_DataAvailable to flush the data to the file)

Comment: @VarandVartanian `StopIt` will trigger `waveIn_RecordingStopped`. `waveIn_RecordingStopped` will make `stopRecording = true`. It should call `StopIt` when `stopRecording = true`. It looks like there is a loop or I misunderstand something in this flow :)

Comment: @PeterBruins need a pause before calling `StopIt()` (until `bool StopRecording` flips) without stopping the whole thread process, because if it stops the recording will stop too.

Answer (score 1):

You say that:

- `StopIt` will trigger `waveIn_RecordingStopped`
- `waveIn_RecordingStopped` will make `stopRecording = true`
- It should call `StopIt` when `stopRecording = true`.

It looks like there is a loop or I misunderstand something in this flow :)

Anyway, you can implement your method this way if you need to wait for `stopRecording` to become `true`:

```
private async void Recorder()
{
    waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
    waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
    waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;
    Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(ExportFolder + @"\" + titleSongName + ".mp3", waveIn.WaveFormat, BitRate);
    waveIn.StartRecording();

    while (!stopRecording)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);
    }

    waveIn.StopRecording();
    Writer.Flush();
    waveIn.Dispose();
    Writer.Dispose();
    Tagger();
}
```

It will poll until `stopRecording` becomes `true` without blocking your thread and causing problems which `while (stopRecording) { }` does.

However, if it all happens in event-based system, it is a good idea to use events. Your `stopRecording` flips when something happens and you need to handle it right there - for instance, when user clicks a "Stop" button, you can call `StopIt()` instead of "flipping `stopRecording`".